# What is equivalent to an hour of "table time" in a play-by-post environment?

Tags: time, gurps-4e, play-by-post

I'm currently playing GURPS on a play-by-post system, and one of my characters has an ability ("Luck", allows me to reroll an attack or ability check and take the better of the two results) that can be used once per hour *as time passes at the table*.

The problem is that in a play-by-post environment, there will often be only one or two "moves" *per day* for most players and the GM, because of needing to wait for other players to post their moves and the GM to respond.

What's a reasonable compromise value on how often I can use Luck in this kind of game?  Clearly, an hour of player time isn't right in this case, else I could use it on virtually every roll.  But an hour of in-game time isn't the intent of the rule; in combat, one might get to use Luck twice or even three times in a battle, but in uneventful travel one might be able to use it only every few game days — or weeks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would suggest using the Game Time enhancement found on page 108 of GURPS Powers.  It's a +0% enhancement that converts powers like Luck, Serendipity, or Wild Talent to uses per game day, rather than table time.

> If it usually works at least once per real hour, you get uses per game day equal to its maximum possible uses per real hour. If it’s rated in uses per session, you get that many uses per game week.

This way, you don't need to worry about real-world time at all.

Comment: Wow, been years since I looked at Powers (Powers in general never made sense me, and weren't balanced against Magic so didn't play well together).  I'll have to run this by my GM.  BTW, this same character also has Wild Talent, so this is relevant to that as well.